# Java: Enum case insensitive Jersey Query Param Binding

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I tried to override/implement all the attribute in [JSR311](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) but the Jersey binding seems case **sensitive**:

1. Be a primitive type
2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
3. Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String))
4. Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

How can I make Jersey binding for enum case insensitive?

**EDIT:**

Here's the code:

The enum:

```
public enum Color {

    GREEN,

    BLUE;

    public Color fromString(String param) {
        String toUpper = param.toUpperCase();
        try {
            return valueOf(toUpper);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Bean Param:

```
 public class FooQueryParam {
        @QueryParam(value = "color")
        private Color color;

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setStatus(Color Color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    }
```

The resource:

```
public Response get(@BeanParam FooQueryParam fooQueryParam) {
            //... 
}
```

Comment: "but the Jersey binding seems case insensitive"... "How can I make Jersey binding for enum case insensitive"... So which is it? It *seems* case insensitive, so how to make it so????

Answer (score 13):

If you're doing it right it shouldn't be a problem. For example in case 3, using a `fromString`

```
public static enum Color {

    RED, GREEN, BLUE;

    public static Color fromString(String param) {
        String toUpper = param.toUpperCase();
        try {
            return valueOf(toUpper);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // default behavior is to send 404 on error.
            // do something else if you want
            throw new WebApplicationException(400);
        }
    }
}
```

Every enum already has a static `valueOf` method which tries to match the enum value exactly, so we override this behavior by defining the `fromString`. We first call `toUpperCase()` *then* call `valueOf` as it's looking for upper case. If anything fails, like a wrong enum value, we send a 400. You can send something else or stick with the normal 404. Up to you.

> I already did this, it is not working

Here is a complete test case.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EnumTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static enum Color {

        RED, GREEN, BLUE;

        public static Color fromString(String param) {
            String toUpper = param.toUpperCase();
            try {
                return valueOf(toUpper);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // default behavior is to send 404 on error.
                // do something else if you want
                throw new WebApplicationException(400);
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Path("enum")
    public static class ColorResource {
        
        @GET
        public String color(@QueryParam("color") Color color) {
            return color.toString();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(ColorResource.class);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void doit() {
        Response response = target("enum").queryParam("color", "blue").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("BLUE", response.readEntity(String.class));
        response.close();
        
        response = target("enum").queryParam("color", "gReEn").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("GREEN", response.readEntity(String.class));
        response.close();

        response = target("enum").queryParam("color", "RED").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("RED", response.readEntity(String.class));
        response.close();
        
        response = target("enum").queryParam("color", "orange").request().get();
        assertEquals(400, response.getStatus());
        response.close();
    }
}
```

Use this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

UPDATE

Test using `@BeanParam`

```
import javax.ws.rs.BeanParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EnumTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static enum Color {

        RED, GREEN, BLUE;

        public static Color fromString(String param) {
            String toUpper = param.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("--- toUpper " + toUpper + "---");
            try {
                return valueOf(toUpper);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(" --- ERROR ---");
                // default behavior is to send 404 on error.
                // do something else if you want
                throw new WebApplicationException(400);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static class FooQueryParam  {
        @QueryParam("color") 
        private Color color;
        public Color getColor() { return color; }
        public void setColor(Color color) { this.color = color; }
    }
    
    @Path("enum")
    public static class ColorResource {
        
        @GET
        public String color(@BeanParam FooQueryParam foo) {
            return foo.getColor().toString();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(ColorResource.class);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void doit() {
        Response response = target("enum").queryParam("color", "blue").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("BLUE", response.readEntity(String.class));
        response.close();
        
        response = target("enum").queryParam("color", "gReEn").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("GREEN", response.readEntity(String.class));
        response.close();
        
        response = target("enum").queryParam("color", "RED").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("RED", response.readEntity(String.class));
        response.close();
        
        response = target("enum").queryParam("color", "orange").request().get();
        assertEquals(400, response.getStatus());
        response.close();
    }
}
```

The only thing that fails is the error case where I am sending a bad color. It seems with `@BeanParam` the behavior is different. Instead of the expected 400, there is a 500. The other case sentiviity issues are fine

Comment: This is a neat solution. The only thing that confuses me a bit is how do you know for sure that Jersey will call `fromString(String)` rather than `valueOf(String)` if both are defined ? Is this behavior specified ?

Comment: @richersoon I'm afraid the only thing left then would be to map that value as a mere `String` and just call `YourEnum.valueOf(input.toUpperCase())`.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu My guess is it's in the algorithm. I know there are different providers for `valueOf` and `fromString`. Without looking into any source code I would guess the `fromString` provider is used first. I've never had a problem with using the for enums. AFAIF, I don't think the behavior is documented anywhere though.

Comment: I added my codes.. is being static is something to do with this?

Comment: No it needs to be `static`. See my update. If you test it, you'll notice only last request test fails, as for some reason not the expected 400 is returned but instead a 500. The rest work fine.

Comment: I ran debug mode, the fromString() is not called

Comment: What version of Jersey are you using?

Comment: I updated the above dependency to 2.22.1 and the test still works fine, ignoring the failing 400 expected for orange. `fromString` is called. What server are you using?

Comment: Also you _do_ realize there is something wrong with the example you posted right (in the `Color` enum, is should return same type as enum class)? Just making sure you don't have the same error in your real code.

Comment: What do you mean by return same type as enum class?
I am running it as  Spring Boot 1.2.7.RELEASE

Comment: look at my `fromString` I am returning `Color`, you are returning `GameRoundStatus`. The return type is not the same type as the class, oh _and_ it's not static which it needs to be

Comment: That was only typo while preparing my question here.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Just to confirm, I just checked out the source code and, the `ParamConverter`s are chosen in the order they are in the array, as seen [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/inject/ParamConverters.java#L294). As you can see the `TypeFromStringEnum` comes before the `TypeValueOf`. If this were not an enum, then `TypeValueOf` comes before the "plain" `TypeFromString` provider

Comment: @peeskillet Cool! They covered it quite well. Good to know; thanks for looking it up.