# Jax Rs: ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> like for QueryParam using @BeanParam

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I would like to intercept the request/response query param, how can I do that using jersey?

Something like for JSON:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    //...
}
```

Bean Param:

```
 public class FooQueryParam {
        @QueryParam(value = "color")
        private Color color;

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setStatus(Color Color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    }
```

The resource:

```
public Response get(@BeanParam FooQueryParam fooQueryParam) {
            //... 
}
```

Comment: Are you asking this question because you are still trying to fix the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33357594/2587435)?

Comment: Nope, this is another issue.. I want to intercept the QueryParam then check the instance then convert into something

Comment: For general filtering, you can see [Filters and Interceptors](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). But if conversion is the goal, then the javadoc for `@QueryParam` explains the ways for conversion. The only non-obvious way is through a `ParamConverterProvider`. You can see an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32677962/2587435)